# Java BigDecimal long with decimal conversion

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a `BigDecimal` value of `123.45`. I'd like to convert it to a `long` value of `12345` and I wonder what's the best way of doing this.

I'd rather avoid doing something like
`val.multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).toBigInteger()`

Comment: `Long.parseLong(bigDecimal.toString().replace(".", ""))`

Comment: `long times100 = new BigDecimal("123.45").multiply(new BigDecimal("100")).longValue();`

Comment: @deHaar aha. I'd assumed `12.345` should have the same result. Guess the requirements are ambiguous

Comment: @Michael possible... OP would have to alter the multiplicator then... Not very elegant, I admit.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the multiplication? It's the fastest way to do this.

Comment: It probably is, but I'd have problem in case my bigdecimal comes with more decimal points than I expect. And I don't particularly like string conversions

Comment: @NomadMaker+ no it's not. `scaleByPowerOfTen` never needs to multiply, and `movePointRight(pos)` or `...Left(neg)` doesn't as long as you don't make the scale negative (then it clamps the scale and multiplies the significand, albeit using precomputed constants rather than needing to re-generate what is actually a constant). Also, using `BigDecimal.longValueExact` _sometimes_ avoids going through an actual `BigInteger`, which is also faster. Although probably not enough you can notice.

Comment: bigdecimal comes with more decimal points than I expect.  - um, a BigDecimal can only ever contain one 'decimal point'. Did you mean: In case the digits after the separator are more or less than 2? This smells of currency. Generally, use a long to represent cents, all throughout the system, not a BD, but I guess you're stuck with this design. Definitely multiply by 100 and convert that, and work out for yourself how you want to deal with 15 bazillion trillion cents (i.e. something that exceeds the long bounds).

Comment: You don't like string conversions and you don't like math conversions.  What's left?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 , thanks, your answer it's what I was looking for. If you care to make it an answer I'll accept it as my preferred solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting this in case you want to know. Made a test for performances, as expected String replacement performed the worst.

results:
movePointRight: 1230
multiply: 833
scaleByPowerOfTen: 591
String replacement: 3289

```
    BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(0);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(123.45);
        val = d.movePointRight(2);
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("movePointRight: " + (end - start));

    BigDecimal ten = new BigDecimal(10);
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(123.45);
        val = d.multiply(new BigDecimal(100));
    }

    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("multiply: " + (end - start));

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(123.45);
        val = d.scaleByPowerOfTen(2);
    }

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(123.45);
        val = d.scaleByPowerOfTen(2);
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("scaleByPowerOfTen: " + (end - start));

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(123.45);
        val =  new BigDecimal(d.toString().replace(".", ""));
    }
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("String replacement: " + (end - start));
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Use to string of BigDecimal and string replace the "." and do a Long.valueOf

Comment: I'd like to avoid string conversion if I can

Comment: How would your approach behave when converting `123.45` and `12.345`?

Comment: @Vargan Next you'll say "I want to avoid long if I can"